# How do I update the android target version on an emulator via the command line?

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm aware that I can do it via the UI (Android Studio), but I'm looking for a way to do it via either the command line or by editing the config files.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a device using AVD Manager, part of Android SDK. That includes Android version, screen resolution, etc. Then you can start emulator from command line (AVD_NAME is the name of your device from AVD Manager).

```
/Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd AVD_NAME
```

See [Start the emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html) for details

You cannot *update emulator version* while it is running, so you need to start another emulator for the required version.

Comment: looks like there is a way to do it, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For eg. to update android target from 21 to 23

1. in `<avd_name>.avd` edit `config.ini`- change 
   `image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86_64/` to
   `image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86_64/`
2. change target from 21 to 23 in `<avd_name>.ini`